# EF can't save into data from list<address> to database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I get data from formcollectionn and store it into list my problem now is my context.saveshange is not saving data into address database is my context is 0 after save ?I really don't know my problem is that because use sql first to build my entities framework?

```
  public class AddressController : Controller
    {

        private readonly CustomersDBEntities context = new CustomersDBEntities();
        //
        // GET: /Address/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // 
        // GET: /Address/Welcome/ 

        public string Welcome()
        {
            return "This is the Welcome action method...";
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Address address)
        {
            //Loop through the request.forms

            var Addesslist = new List<Address>();
            for (int i = 1; i <= Request.Form.Count; i++)
            {
                var street = Request.Form["street_0" + i + ""];
                var city = Request.Form["city_0" + i + ""];
                var postalCode = Request.Form["postalCode_0" + i + ""];
                var province = Request.Form["province_0" + i + ""];
                var personID = 1;
                if (street != null && city != null && postalCode != null && province != null)
                {
                    Addesslist.Add(new Address { Street = street, City = city, Province = province, PostalCode = postalCode, PersonID = personID });

                    Addesslist.ForEach(p => context.SaveChanges());
                    if (context.SaveChanges() == Addesslist.Count)
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Redirect to an error page or

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }

            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are saving once for each item in `Addesslist`. By the time you get to the `context.SaveChanges()` in your `if` statement, there are no more changes to save.

Comment: just want to ask is there are any bulk inset for line?

Comment: @rikitikitik have remove the if but still no data in my database

Comment: Have you debugged your code? Are you 100% sure that Address objects are being created? Another thing I noticed is that if at anytime `(street != null && city != null && postalCode != null && province != null)` is false, you break the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can  use this code snippet to make it work

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Address address)
    {
        //Loop through the request.forms

        var Addesslist = new List<Address>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= Request.Form.Count; i++)
        {
            var street = Request.Form["street_0" + i + ""];
            var city = Request.Form["city_0" + i + ""];
            var postalCode = Request.Form["postalCode_0" + i + ""];
            var province = Request.Form["province_0" + i + ""];
            var personID = 1;
            if (street != null && city != null && postalCode != null && province != null)
            {

                try
                {
                    context.Addresses.Add(new Address
                    {
                        Street = street,
                        City = city,
                        Province = province,
                        PostalCode = postalCode,
                        PersonID = personID
                    });
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception exc)
                {

                }
            }
            else
            {
                break;
            }

        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```